# Почему пропадает курсор при повторном запуске Меню unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть главное меню которое запускается при запуске игры, появляется курсор мыши, в нем кнопка которая запускает другую сцену. Когда из другой сцены вызываешь это же меню, курсор мыши пропадает и нажать другую кнопку в меню невозможно, как решить проблему, что бы курсор появлялся каждый раз когда запускается сцена Menu?

главное меню:

```
public class mainmanu : MonoBehaviour {

public void training(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene (2);
}

public void practice(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene (3);
}

public void QuitButton(){
    Application.Quit ();
}
```

Запуск главного меню из другой сцены:

```
public class menu : MonoBehaviour {
//bool isLocked;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
        SceneManager.LoadScene (1);
    }
}
        }
```

Comment: Возможно в другой сцене вы делаете сокрытие курсора. Пробовали в загрузке сцены с меню добавлять Cursor.Visible = true; ?

Comment: @test123 добавила в mainmenu `void Start(){
  Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
  Cursor.visible = true;
 }`
работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class mainmenu : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start(){
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
    public void training(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene (2);
    }

    public void practice(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene (3);
    }

    public void QuitButton(){
        Application.Quit ();
    }
```

Comment: Вообще, я бы рекомендовал создать менеджер состояний сцены, который позволял бы переключать глобальный статус на GUI/Game и прочие состояния, а уже он пускай руководит, нужен ли курсор в текущем состоянии или нет. Постоянно дёргать курсор вручную туда-сюда неудобно, особенно если проект большой, а вот менять текущее состояние - в порядке вещей, и пускай уже сам менеджер берёт на себя работу по переключению дополнительных вещей, будь то видимость курсора, настройки камеры или любая другая прихоть, которую вы придумаете. Но, всё это, конечно, ИМХО.